# Weird crash when adding new instance in NSMutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, unnotificationrequest

EDIT: iOS Version: iOS 10

I am puzzled with following crash report from crashlytics:

```
CoreFoundation             0x142ea9823 CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding + 806
MyApp                      0x100d3625c -[MyClass myMethod:] (Myclass.m:100)
```

Here is the implementation:

```
NSMutableArray *myActions = [NSMutableArray array];
UNNotificationAction *action = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"actionId" title:@"title" options:UNNotificationActionOptionNone];
[myActions addObject:action];//Line no. 100
```

I am not able to see the crash in dev environment but when I deploy the app in AppStore, get the number of crashes reported in the same line `[myActions addObject:action];`

Comment: Could you please share the *full* call stack from Crashlytics? Or (even better) attach the crash report.

Answer (score 3):

This may be Happening in the Lower versions of iOS prior to the Version 10.0 because UNNotificationAction Api is available in iOS version that are equal to or greate then iOS 10.0 you can find more detail information [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationaction?language=objc). Maybe your deployment target is less then 10.0?